# call file php in file tpl

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I have a php file in which I recover data from a database and then I would like to use this data in a tpl file.

my code php :

```
require_once('../lib_smarty/Smarty.class.php');

 try
{
    $smarty = new Smarty();

    $mysql_ressource = mysql_connect('******', 'nameBDD', 'mdpBDD');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

$sQuery = "SELECT `id_product` FROM `ps_category_product` WHERE `id_category`= 252 OR `id_category` = 60 OR `id_category`= 128 OR `id_category` = 117";


$smarty->assign('prod', $mysql_ressource->getAssoc($sQuery));

$smarty->display('shopping-cart.tpl');
```

and my tpl :

```
{foreach  item=foo from=$prod }
<p>{$foo}</p>
{/foreach}
```

But it does not work.
I have the impression that the php file is never executed.

What does someone see why?

Thanks.

Comment: What template system is this `twig` that would be my guess from looking at it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak English very well and I'm not sure I understand this question.
But I work on Prestashop and I search to recover id in my database for sent to a tpl file for display.